# ANTLR4 Exceptions in Prototype

Tags: java, exception, antlr4

I use ANTLR4 to create my parser in Java. Each rule in my ANTLR4 parser is created as a function in Java, and each function throws "RecognitionException" by default (in its prototype).
For example the rule "automaton" that I define in "parser.g4" is created as a function called "automaton" in "parser.java" which throws "RecognitionException" in its prototype:

```
public final AutomatonContext automaton() throws RecognitionException
```

I want to not only throw "RecognitionException" but also throw my own exceptions in the prototype, for example:

```
public final AutomatonContext automaton() throws RecognitionException, ExceptionTypeA, ExceptionTypeB
```

I know how to make a "try-catch" in ANTLR4 script (just write something like `catch[RecognitionException e] { throw e; }` after the rule definition), but I want to use "throws" in the prototype and I don't want to use "try-catch" in the current function body (because I don't want to handle these exceptions in the current function).

For the moment, my solution is to add it by myself after generating "parser.java". But I still want to know if there're some ways to make it when I write the ANTLR4 script "parser.g4".

Comment: Would need to modify the language target code generation template. But, even then, the exceptions would never be thrown by the generated code, so it would appear to be meaningless.  A more in-depth explanation of what is trying to be accomplished would gain a better alternate solution.

Comment: Just throw a `RuntimeException` different from `RecognitionException`.